# Wie sagt man „I am making my lesson plan“ auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, verb-usage, verb-choice

Ich weiß nicht, ob ich das Verb *machen* in diesem Zusammenhang verwenden kann:

> Ich mache meinen Lehrplan.

Kann ich auch das Verb *ordnen* in diesem Kontext benutzen? :

> Ich ordne meinen Lehrplan.

Was ist, wenn man Student ist – kann man dann beides verwenden?

Comment: NB: Einen _Lehrplan_ würde ein Student nur dann aufstellen, wenn er als TA oder SHK verpflichtet wird und selbst Lehrveranstaltungen abhält. Als Teilnehmer macht man wohl eher einen _Lernplan_.

Comment: Was bedeuten TA u SHK ?

Comment: Sorry! TA = Teaching Assistant; SHK = Studentische Hilfskraft. Wobei, TAs sind wohl häufiger post-graduates.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Als Student hat man wie als Schüler eher einen **Stundenplan**, wenn es um Lehrveranstaltungen geht. Einen Lernplan erstellt man sich zur Klausurvorbereitung.

Comment: @Crissov auch Recht

Comment: *Lehrplan* ist für mich das dicke Dokument, das das Kultusministerium herausgibt, in welchem steht, welche Konzepte die Schüler in welcher Jahrgangsstufe beigebracht bekommen sollen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich als Deutscher würde eines der Folgenden sagen:

> Ich schreibe meinen Lehrplan.
>
> Ich erstelle meinen Lehrplan.

»*Ich ordne meinen Lehrplan« würde ich nicht sagen.

*Ordnen* könnte man verwenden, wenn man mehrere Lehrpläne hat, und diese in eine sinnvolle Reihenfolge bringen will, dann aber:

> Ich ordne meine Lehrpläne.

Comment: "Ich ordne meinen Lehrplan", könnte man auch so verstehen, dass man die zu lehrenden Inhalte in eine sinnvolle Reihenfolge bringt. Insgesamt wurde ich aber auch noch zwischen Lehrplan und Stundenplan unterscheiden. Ersterer legt die Inhalte fest, Zweiterer sagt, zu welchen Uhrzeiten welche Fächer gelehrt werden.